# Location of xml files containing data in android

Tags: java, android, xml, input, output

For my application, I have stored data that I will want to view in my own way to the user. Let's say these xml files have a list of pills and patients in them, and that I want to modify them whenever the user enters a new pill or patient.

I though of first putting it in the asset folder, however, I read the files in asset folder are read-only.
Then I though of putting them in res/xml folder, but I can't find a way to write to the xml file, when browsing through the Resource documentation, all I could open was an InputStream, and I can't write to the file with InputStream.
Then I though of putting it in sd card, but I am a little hesitant as I don't want the user to mess the xml files.

Where should I store the xml file for reading and writing purposes?

Thanks

Comment: you can not write file in resource folder you have to put it to sd card for writing. you have other option to store data and read/write run time, like shared pref and database.

Comment: If I store them shared pref or database with the user still be able to see the raw data?

Comment: no user can not see your database because it secure by android if he/she not root his phone but they can clear data from setting.

Comment: Ohh okay, and can I prevent them from being able to clear data from setting, because what if they pressed it by mistake or something

Comment: when user cleardata from setting everything will be lost like databse info,password..etc we can not prevent this.

Comment: Ohh okay, then can I keep a backup of them someplace on the smartphone and maybe encrypt it, so that in case the user clears we can have a backup?